# How to add margin for a button in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, layout

In my Flex application I have a button with the following declaration placed above a custom data-grid component.

```
<mx:Button id="resetButton" label="Reset" visible="true" />
```

The button is now placed just above the grid and I would need to move it a few pixels higher so that there is a little space between them.

I noticed that there is a `paddingBottom` attribute for the Button component but no `marginBottom` equivalent.

I could not find any advice on Google. What is the correct way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT:**

The bottom property did not have any effect in my case (perhaps due to the layout we used) so I ended up surrounding the Button with a new VBox component like this:

```
<mx:VBox paddingBottom="5">
  <mx:Button id="resetButton" label="Reset" visible="true" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `top, bottom, left, right` attribute instead of `marginTop, marginBottom, marginLeft, marginRight`. The function of `top` is same as `marginTop`

```
<mx:Button id="btnSave"
           top="50"
           bottom="50"
           left="50"
           right="50"
           click="btnSave_clickHandler(event)"
           label="SAVE to File" />
```

May this will help you.

Comment: I tried to add a bottom="20" attribute but it did not change. Do you have any ideas about what the reason might be?

Comment: please give me layout of designing else write your mxml(designing) code here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your button and grid are already in a VBox. If that is the case, you can simply add a spacer after the button. It is much more lightweight than surrounding a single button with a VBox.

```
<mx:Spacer height="5"/>
```